# plotly heatmap in R - change scale title

Tags: r, plotly

I've created a heat map in R using `plot_ly`, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to change the name that appears above the colour legend (short of changing the name of the input dataframe).

Trouble is, I'd like spaces in the name of the title, which passing as the data to the `plotly` call makes difficult.

There MUST be a way to edit it directly as there is for every other label/title surely?!

I was hoping it would inherit from `legend=` but seemingly no.. Code and output image below (trying to change the bit that currently says "data.matrix, adjwallace").

(I havent provided the data, since it isn't relevant to the particular problem I don't think - and I had to mess with it's format, but I can edit if necessary).

```
fonts <- list(
family = "sans-serif",
size = 12
)

x.axisSettings <- list(
 title = "",
 zeroline = FALSE,
 showline = FALSE,
 showticklabels = TRUE,
 showgrid = FALSE,
)

y.axisSettings <- list(
  title = "",
  zeroline = FALSE,
  showline = FALSE,
  showticklabels = TRUE,
  showgrid = FALSE,
)

legend.Settings <- list(
  font = fonts,
  title = "Adjusted Wallace Coefficients"
)

plot_ly(z = data.matrix(adjwallace),
        colorscale= "Hot",
        name = "Adjusted Wallace Coefficients",
        x = names(adjwallace),
        y = names(adjwallace),
        type = "heatmap") %>%
  layout(xaxis=x.axisSettings,
         yaxis=y.axisSettings,
         legend=legend.Settings)
```

[image]

Comment: could you simply create/rename data.matrix(adjwallace) before your plot?

Comment: I had thought that (and admittedly I haven't actually _tried_ this), but, as I say, I want the eventual title to have spaces in, and I'm taking an educated guess that R isn't going to like a variable with spaces in the name. I guess it's possible that it could just treat it as a string, or that I could delimit it, like `Adjusted\ Wallace\ Coefficients`- but that seems like a bodge compared to a functionality I'm pretty sure I'm just missing?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just specify the title inside the colorbar argument. See [here](https://plot.ly/r/reference/#heatmap-colorbar) for more details...

```
library(plotly)

data("edhec", package = "PerformanceAnalytics")

plot_ly(z = cov(edhec), type = "heatmap", 
        colorbar = list(title = "Edhec Covariance"))
```

Comment: Perfect! Many thanks... I knew it should have been that easy.